# Docker Node-Alpine: puppeteer-core@1.20.0 throw error in page.pdf()

Tags: docker, dockerfile, chromium, puppeteer, alpine-linux

When checking [puppeteer document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-core/v/1.20.0), it requires to install **puppeteer-core** since version *1.17.0*. However, I would like to install puppeteer & puppeteer-core with version 1.20.0 in below *Dockerfile* (suppose that when I install puppeteer-core, Chromium version 77 should be downloaded), there is error comes out.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"\
    PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
RUN set -x \
    && apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" > /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    #### chromium: used to run Puppeteer
    && apk add --no-cache g++ chromium \
    #### install NodeJS related packages
    && npm install puppeteer@1.20.0 puppeteer-core@1.20.0
...
```

Case 1: If run without change in Dockerfile:

> Error: Protocol error (IO.read): Invalid parameters handle: string value expected
>         at /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56
>         at new Promise ()
>         at CDPSession.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
>         at Function.readProtocolStream (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:250:37)
>         at async Page.pdf (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:994:12)
>         at async printPdf (/usr/src/app/Testing.js:252:5)

```
// Testing.js:252 
await page.pdf({
    path: 'tmp/file',
    format: printOptions.format,
    printBackground: true
});
```

Case 2: If skip `apk add --no-cache g++ chromium` in Dockerfile:

> Error: Failed to launch chrome! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT

**Questions:**

1. With puppeteer-core install why can't I use Chromium?
2. How to download Chromium version 77/latest?

Comment: see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker

Comment: Yes, saw that "The newest Chromium package supported on Alpine is 76, which corresponds to Puppeteer v1.17.0." But I faced some ExtJS components missing while printed in v1.19.0 is okay. So just want to see the questions above.

Comment: try find answer here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Yes, I know *The newest Chromium package supported on Alpine is 76, which corresponds to Puppeteer v1.17.0.*  Maybe I just wait for Alpine update Chromium version later, thanks.